# Detect when node edges are dragged into group in GoJS

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

I want to drag a node into a group, and when the node's edges enter the group, highlight the group, and when dropping, add the node to the group.

For example, if I'm holding the node from the left corner, so to be able to drag the node into the group when doing this:

[image]

Instead of entering the mouse into the group, like this:

[image]

All of the examples (e.g. [regroupingTreeView](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/regroupingTreeView.html)) use [`mouseDragEnter`](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphObject.html#mouseDragEnter), which means only when the mouse enters the group.
This way if I drag a node from the left corner to the group to its right, it means I have to drag the whole node into the group, which is less intuitive.

Thanks!

Comment: Your suggested policy is ambiguous.  What should happen when a dragged Node overlaps two or more different Groups?

Comment: The group that contains the largest area of the node should be highlighted.